# multiple たとえ even if (in a compound sentense)

Tags: grammar, syntax

> たとえ夏にあなたにあえなくても、たとえいっしょに旅しなくても、まだもっと待ってるよ。

The question is how to link two "even if's" in a compound sentence, as in the example above. Perhaps, You don't need two たとえ and if you only conjugate the て, adding the も to the second one, will it be clear enough? Or is there a better way to express this kind of sentence?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It works for emphasis. 'Even if I cannot meet you in the summer, even if I cannot journey with you, I will always remain waiting.'

Comment: もっと as in まだ もっと 待ってる doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

These two even-if-clauses are simply placed in parallel ("Even if ～, (and) even if ～, I will keep waiting for you."). Effectively, this sentence is the following two sentences said together.

1. たとえ夏にあなたに会えなくても、まだもっと待ってるよ。
2. たとえいっしょに旅しなくても、まだもっと待ってるよ。

(I feel this もっと is a bit weird, but let me keep it for now)

You cannot combine these clauses into one using て, because "夏に会えない" and "一緒に旅しない" are independent from each other.

> たとえ夏にあなたに会えなくて一緒に旅しなくても、まだ待ってるよ。

This sentence is grammatical, but sounds like "Even if I don't travel with you together **because** I can't see you in summer, I will keep waiting for you," which is very different from the original nuance.

Comment: Doesn't て combine the two words and means and, not because? So it will be 'even if i cannot meet you in summer and cannot go travel with you'. Cmwii :)

Comment: @Alice28 Nope, it doesn't always mean "and" -- there can be very many different relationships between the two connected things. Check out http://socrates.berkeley.edu/~hasegawa/TE-Linkage/TE-linkage.html